# Performance issues instantiating classes containing defined variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, chromium, es6-class

I've noticed some strange behaviour in Javascript when a `class` with `defined variables` is instanced.

Note: the code below simply serves as a reproduction case for this specific issue.

Let's consider the following class:

```js
class Vector3
{
    #unused1;
    #unused2;
    #unused3;
    #unused4;
    #unused5;
    #unused6;
    #unused7;
    #unused8;
    #unused9;
    #unused10;
    #unused11;
    #unused12;
    #unused13;

    constructor(x, y, z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

And the following script:

```js
let frames = 0;
let p = 0;
let fn = () => {

    let now = performance.now();
    let sum;
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        var vector = new Vector3(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random());
        var o = new Vector3(vector.x + Math.random(), vector.y + Math.random(), vector.z + Math.random());
    }

    // check the amount of passed frames every second
    if (now - p >= 1000) {
        console.log(frames);
        // added to also test performance without having Dev Tools open
        document.documentElement.innerText = frames;
        frames = 0;
        p = now;
    }

    frames++;

    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        return fn();
    })
    return;
}
fn();
```

When running the above and viewing the console we can see performance is around (depending on your specs), 30 to 35 frames.

Now, if we modify the class to contain no defined variables as such:

```js
class Vector3
{
    constructor(x, y, z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

We can see performance go up to (again, depending on your specs) 60 frames and above.

At first I thought this issue had to do with `garbage collection` but after checking the `Chrome Profiler` I noticed most of the performance was being eaten up by `getting` variables and after further research/benchmarking I noticed this issue didn't actually have to do with variables `in use`, but variables `declared`.

Also important to note is that it doesn't seem to "matter" if the variable is declared as `private` or `public`.

Does anyone have an explanation for why this issue occurs?

Update: this issue seems affect `Chromium` more than `Firefox`. `Firefox` "always" seems to hit 60.

Comment: Declaring the properties tells the runtime that it should make room for them in the allocated objects. Even though they're not used, the objects are larger, so your loop overall allocates considerably more memory.

Comment: `#unused1` etc. are [private fields](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields), not “declared variables”. Is the performance issue still there if the profiler is not enabled?

Comment: @SebastianSimon the profiler itself doesn't seem to affect performance in this case. Neither does having the Dev Tools open or not.

Comment: @Pointy that's also what I've been thinking. If that were the case then it's better not to declare variables in Javascript due to this kind of pollution/performance issue.

I've also tested with numerous getters and setters and these don't seem to influence performance which is strange, because the class prototype gets extended not so much different than adding variables does.

Comment: Well it's certainly a good idea not to declare variables that you're not going to use. However, on the other hand by declaring private fields that you actually *will* use means that the allocation mechanism can allocate properly-sized objects. Without the declarations, adding new properties can itself impose performance penalties.

Comment: @Pointy that's exactly my point. In this "vector" class it's just 3 getters and setters but in other classes (Quaternions, Transform, and such) the amount of private variables is much higher due to type checking/casting.

This is just one class, containing 10 privates which aren't even being used in the first place.

Comment: @BRO_THOM Well, getters/setters don't need to be duplicated in memory for each instance of the class, unlike fields (which are necessarily per-instance).

Comment: @AKX that's true, my comparison was pretty bad in that case. So I'm basically left with no other choice than just refraining from using variable definitions in classes due to them hurting performance but massively increasing the chance of error due to user input.

Comment: What kind of user input? If you're talking about programmers, maybe look at TypeScript...

Comment: @AKX the userbase for my project are programmers. TypeScript also contributes nothing to my case due to this fundamental issue also existing there.

Comment: If you want to use fields to avoid "massively increasing the chance of error due to user input" what is the source of that error? Typos? TypeScript helps with that.

Comment: @BRO_THOM Still, it's not *variables* (declared with `let` or `const` or `function` etc), they're fields of the object. And if you don't use them, why would you put them in the class? What getters and setters are you talking about? Please show us your actual code, and explain how add unused stuff "*increases the chance of error*".

Answer (score 0):

The performance issue you highlight was an unoptimized case where initializing fields was slow.  That existed until Chrome 96.  It is now fixed in Chrome 97 which was released at the start of January 2022.

Here's [some evidence.](https://gist.github.com/robpalme/a9ff3e4764b764d7dc24743816d8a624)

Comment: Wait, really? I'll check the case above again to see if the issue has been resolved.